# Confusion related to the calculation of gradient

Tags: convex-optimization, subgradient

I am having some confusion related to the calculation of gradient.

[image]

My function $f(X) = g(X) + \lambda||X||_1$ where g(X) is convex and differentiable. I didn't get how the second expression when $X_{ij}=0$ is derived

Comment: The gradient of $x \mapsto \|x\|_1$ is not defined when any component of $x$ is zero. It has a directional and generalized directional derivative, but not a gradient at these points.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I found the reason. It's related to minimum norm subgradient http://www.di.ens.fr/~mschmidt/Documents/2011_OPT_Chapter.pdf.